How Take User 2 Connection Id In ASP .NET Core Web Api Using SignalR
I want to user 1 send a message to user 2 but to do that i have to take user 2 connection Id
So when everytime I try to send a message it takes user 1 connection Id and add it to this code
public async Task SendMessage(string targetConnectionId, string message)
{
    //await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", targetConnectionId, message);

    await Clients.User(user).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", targetConnectionId, message); 
}

so how can i take user 2 connection Id so I can send a message to him from user 1 to user 2

You have a couple of options here.
Option 1
Track connectionId's when a connecting
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _userConnections = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    { 
        var userId = GetUserId(Context.User); // some way to identify the user
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

      //TODO: Save the user ID and connection ID somewhere, or store in a dictonary

        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

Option 2 would be to use group messaging instead of client messaging. Something
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public async Task LeaveGroup(string groupName)
    {
        await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public async Task SendMessageToGroup(string groupName, string message)
    {
        await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", Context.ConnectionId, message);
    }
}


Every 2 users will join one group ?

We typically use ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> to store the user's connection information.
Here's the simplest sample code below you can check out, and we usually recommend creating a UserConnectionManager to use, which can be found in detail at this link.
Test Result

Test Code
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SignalRMiddleawre.Hubs
{

    [Authorize]
    public partial class MainHub : Hub
    {
        #region Connection
        /// <summary>
        /// Use ConcurrentDictionary to save connected users's id and connectionId
        /// </summary>
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>? ConnectedUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();

        /// <summary>
        ///  OnConnectedAsync method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userid"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// 
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {

            string? userid = Context.User?.Identity?.Name;
            if (userid == null || userid.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("user not loged in, can't connect signalr service");
                return;
            }
            Trace.TraceInformation(userid + "connected");
            // save connection
            List<string>? existUserConnectionIds = null;
            ConnectedUsers?.TryGetValue(userid, out existUserConnectionIds);
            if (existUserConnectionIds == null)
            {
                existUserConnectionIds = new List<string>();
            }
            existUserConnectionIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
            ConnectedUsers?.TryAdd(userid, existUserConnectionIds);
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// OnDisconnectedAsync
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userid"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
        {
            string? userid = Context.User?.Identity?.Name;
            // save connection
            List<string>? existUserConnectionIds= new List<string>() ;

            ConnectedUsers?.TryGetValue(userid, out existUserConnectionIds);

            existUserConnectionIds?.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);

            if (existUserConnectionIds?.Count == 0)
            {
                List<string> garbage;
                ConnectedUsers?.TryRemove(userid, out garbage);
            }

            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Message
        
        public async Task SendToSingleUser(string userid, string message)
        {
            List<string>? existUserConnectionIds = null;

            ConnectedUsers?.TryGetValue(userid, out existUserConnectionIds);

            if (existUserConnectionIds == null)
            {
                existUserConnectionIds = new List<string>();
            }
            existUserConnectionIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
            ConnectedUsers?.TryAdd(userid, existUserConnectionIds);

            string? fromUser = Context.User?.Identity?.Name;
            string? ToUser = userid;
            await Clients.Clients(existUserConnectionIds).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage_SpecificUser", fromUser,ToUser, message);
        }
        #endregion

    }
}


in this code "string? fromUser = Context.User?.Identity?.Name;" it gives me null and ToUser value is actually fromUser value like the value that should be on fromUser its goes to ToUser and its becomes like from null to user 1

@AbdalhmeedShishani Seems you are not use default identity, ok , you can try to append userid when connect the hub, and achieve it like this.

i'm using abp.io framework so idk if its will effect or not

@AbdalhmeedShishani You can try it.
